# getting error on destroy item

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have 1 crud of project and I am trying to destroy project from list as using ajax.

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
.
.
.
 def destroy
    @project.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

end
```

destroy.js

```
$('#all_projects').html("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'projects/all_projects') %>");
```

all_projects.html.erb

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Team size</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @projects.each do |project| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= project.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', project %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } ,:remote=>true%></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing Projects</h1>

<div id="all_project">
  <%= render 'projects/all_projects'%>
</div>
```

When I try to load all project it's working fine.
But when I destroy the project it will give me an error in server side like below:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
     9:   </thead>
    10: 
    11:   <tbody>
    12:     <% @projects.each do |project| %>
    13:       <tr>
    14:         <td><%= project.team_size %></td>
  app/views/projects/_all_projects.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_projects__all_projects_html_erb___3489379756657223366_70218666904220'
```

What do I missed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because of missing object `@project` details.

when i put `@projects = Project.all` in destroy method this error is gone and function is working fine.